# Multiple Files communication with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

When I create a new coffeescript file, I cannot access the code in the compiled code from another file because it gets wrapped in some function scope. For example:

CoffeeScript:

```
class ChatService
  constructor: (@io) ->
```

Generated Javascript:

```
(function() {
  var ChatService;    
  ChatService = (function() {    
    function ChatService(io) {
      this.io = io;
    }    
    return ChatService;    
  })();    
}).call(this);
```

When trying to call `ChatService` in another file, it's not defined. How do I handle multiple files with coffeescript?

Comment: If you're using Rails, you have to make sure any dependent coffeescript file is called *before* you try and reference it. Once you set "require" directives in the files which actually need the others, you'll get access to the variables etc.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Depending on whether this is client- or server-side code, there are two slightly different approaches.

Client-side: Here we attach things that should be available across files to the global namespace (`window`) as follows:

```
class window.ChatService
  constructor: (@io) ->
```

Then, in another file both `ChatService` and `window.ChatService` will allow access to the class.

---

Server-side: Here we must use `exports` and `require`.  In the `ChatService.coffee` file, you would have the following:

```
class exports.ChatService
  constructor: (@io) ->
```

Then, to get at it from another file you can use:

```
ChatService = require('ChatService.coffee').ChatService
```

Note: If there are multiple classes that you are getting from ChatService.coffee, this is one place where CoffeeScript's dict unpacking really shines, such as:

```
{ChatService, OtherService} = require('ChatService.coffee')
```

---

Both: Basically, we choose whether to run server-side or client-side code based on which environment we're in.  A common way to do it:

```
class ChatService
  constructor: (@io) ->

if typeof module != "undefined" && module.exports
  #On a server
  exports.ChatService = ChatService
else
  #On a client
  window.ChatService = ChatService
```

To get it:

```
if typeof module != "undefined" && module.exports
  #On a server
  ChatService = require("ChatService.coffee").ChatService
else
  #On a client
  ChatService = window.ChatService
```

The else clause of the second block can be skipped, since `ChatService` already refers to the reference attached to `window`.

If you're going to define a lot of classes in this file, it may be easier to define them like:

```
self = {}

class self.ChatService
```

And then attach them like `module.exports = self` on the server and `_.extend(window, self)` on the client (replace `_.extend` with another `extend` function as appropriate).

Comment: Thanks for giving both node.js and client side approach, I needed both.

Comment: Like the answer from "mu is too short", you may be able to do an exports.App.ClassName as well.  I guess you could call the App portion of that a "namespace".  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: How does this work if the code is used both client-side and server-side? e.g. I have a client-side code, but am testing it with jasmine-node where there is no window object.

Comment: @AaronDufour thanks, that helps, but this is leading to more questions. One of my goals is to keep from adding classes to the window object as I don't want to accidentally overwrite an existing object from some other library or package. Thus, I want to wrap my classes from multiple files in another object. I haven't been able to successfully do this. It is easy to wrap multiple classes from a single file in a container object, but hard to wrap classes from multiple files in a container object. Not sure if this is on-topic...

Comment: @kindohm You're veering a bit too far from the topic of this question.  I would suggest creating a new question.

Comment: Just a small detail to add: `if typeof module != "undefined" && module.exports` can be simplified greatly to `if module?.exports?`.

Comment: @snickle I agree, but here I avoided use of `?` operator to keep it readable for people who are using js and don't know coffeescript.

Answer (score 24):

The usual approach is to define a global namespace in `window`:

```
window.App = { }
```

That would go somewhere in your application's initialization code before anything else happens. And then, for your class:

```
class App.ChatService
  constructor: (@io) ->
```

That allows you to reference your class through `App` anywhere you want and you don't have to worry about polluting the global namespace:

```
chatter = new App.ChatService
```

If you wanted to make your `ChatService` truly global then you could use `class window.ChatService` but I'd recommend against that except in the most trivial of applications.

AFAIK, node.js has something similar to `window` but I'm not familiar enough with node.js to tell you what it is.

Comment: In node.js, you export symbols by attaching them to `exports`. In one module: exports.ChatService = ChatService; In the other: ChatService = require("./chat").ChatService.

Comment: @Linus: Thanks, I think Aaron Dufour covered that before I got to it.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your classes with namespaces and use [***cake***](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/cake.html) to compile them all in one (or more) resulting .js file(s). Cakefile is used as configuration which controls in which order your coffee scripts are compiled - quite handy with bigger projects.

Cake is quite easy to install and setup, invoking cake from vim while you are editing your project is then simply

```
:!cake build
```

and you can refresh your browser and see results.

As I'm also busy to learn the best way of structuring the files and use coffeescript in combination with backbone and cake, I have created a [***small project on github***](https://github.com/pericazivkovic/coffeescript-backbone-sample) to keep it as a reference for myself, maybe it will help you too around cake and some basic things. All compiled files are in **www** folder so that you can open them in your browser and all source files (except for cake configuration) are in **src** folder. In this example, all .coffee files are compiled and combined in **one** output .js file which is then included in html.