# coffeescript Class not accessible in main javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have a class written in coffeescript, e.g.,

```
class Example
  constructor: ->
    $.each [1, 2, 3], (key, value) =>
      @test = value
    return @test
  render: ->
    alert @test
```

and I have this class as a separate file, Example.coffee

Now I want to be able to instantiate in my main javascript file like so:

```
d = new Example
d.render()
```

but the class is undefined even when it is included as a script on the page, like

```
<script src="Example.js></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

How do you make the class publicly available to the main file?

Comment: Flagged as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287510/multiple-files-communication-with-coffeescript/9296803

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can declare your class to be globally accessible (at least for browsers) by declaring it to be in the `window` namespace:

```
class window.Example
  constructor: ->
    $.each [1, 2, 3], (key, value) =>
      @test = value
    return @test
  render: ->
    alert @test
```

That will put `Example` straight into `window`. You can also say `class @Example` in most cases.

By default, CoffeeScript wraps each file in a `(function() { ... })()` wrapper to prevent namespace pollution. You can prevent this by supplying [`-b`](http://coffeescript.org/#usage) when compiling your CoffeeScript:

> `-b, --bare`
>   Compile the JavaScript without the top-level function safety wrapper.

but that might not be an option for you (or it might be an ugly one). The usual approach is to declare an application specific namespace somewhere before your classes are loaded:

```
// Probably in a <script> in your top-level HTML...
App = { };
```

and then namespace your classes appropriately:

```
class App.Example
    #...
```

Then refer to everything through the `App` namespace.

Comment: Is there anyway to setup the namespace without having to resort to a script tag?  Didn't get very far in my attempts.  Thanks!

Comment: @MichaeldeSilva: In a browser environment you can say things like `@App ?= { }` before your classes to initialize `window.App` if it isn't already around. Or you could say `class @C` to put your classes in the global scope if that fits. Or you could use a module system like require.js.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old thread, but in case anyone else finds it useful, declare your class with "@" and it will be accessible to `.js` files outside of the `.coffee` file.

So, in `example.coffee`:

```
class Introverted
  honk: ->
    alert "This class is visible within the .coffee file but not outside"

class @Extroverted
  honk: ->
    alert "This class is visible inside and outside of the .coffee file"
```

That is compiled to `example.js` which can then be used in `example.html`:

```
<script src="example.js"></script>
<script>
var p = new Extroverted(); // works fine
p.honk();

var i = new Introverted(); // will fail with "Introverted is not defined"
i.honk();
</script>
```

Comment: This is effectively the same as `mu is too short`'s answer. The `@Extroverted` will compile to `this.Extroverted`, which is effectively the same as `window.Extroverted` in this case.

Comment: Just to add to Nick's comment above, in case anyone is wondering... the reason why this works is because `@` is a shortcut for `this.` in coffeescript. And like he says, in the above context `this` is `window` so you're attaching Extraverted to window, effectively making it global.

Answer (score 4):

Create a global variable

`window.Example = Example`