# Why is coffescript creating this closure

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm learning CoffeeScript I have this code:

```
class Person
    constructor: (@firstName, @lastName) ->
    sayHi: () ->
        return "Hi, I'm #{@firstName} #{@lastName}"
```

And is generating this javascript code:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.10.0
(function() {
  var Person;

  Person = (function() {
    function Person(firstName, lastName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    Person.prototype.sayHi = function() {
      return "Hi, I'm " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    };

    return Person;

  })();

}).call(this);
```

I want to create instances of that `class`, but since it's inside the closure I can't how should I do that?

Comment: You should mention that you are using `node.js`?

Comment: I'm not using `node`. Just `npm` for install some packages but it is just front end app for now

Comment: I want to run jasmine tests over this, but when I `require` the js file, Person is undefined since it is in the closure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214731/coffeescript-global-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option that is slightly less hackish is the `@` operator (which is the same as `this`). In a browser environment, `this` will point to `window`, in `node.js`, it will point to `exports`.

```
class @Person
  constructor: (@firstName, @lastName) ->
  sayHi: () ->
    return "Hi, I'm #{@firstName} #{@lastName}"
```

`window.Person` only works on the browser, the `@` will work for node and the browser. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24352630/227299

Alternatively, you can run coffescript with the `-b` `(--bare)` option and the wrapping function won't be created.

Answer (score 0):

change a bit declaration of a class

```
class window.Person
  constructor: (@firstName, @lastName) ->
  sayHi: () ->
    return "Hi, I'm #{@firstName} #{@lastName}"
```

Comment: is this the correct way to make it work in `coffee`?