# How to use a function from one CoffeeScript module in other one? Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

There is the following question: I have some shared JS function in shared.js.coffee module. I want to use these functions, for example, in module some_actions.js.coffee. So, but I don't know how I should share functions in the first module properly. Please, give me advice to do it well. Thanks.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9296803/3797480

Answer (score 0):

In these situations it is best to use  the Paloma gem (https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma) and use it whenever required, for example, use it like so :

```
gem 'paloma'
```

You can then code this is in `application.js or shared.js.coffee` but make sure that you have

```
//= require shared.js.coffee
```

in your application.js. And then you con do like this :

```
var UsersController = Paloma.controller('Users');

// Executes when Rails User#new is executed.
UsersController.prototype.new = function(){
   alert('Hello User!' );
};
```

In your controller :

```
def UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
      # a Paloma request will automatically be created.
      @user = User.new
    end
end
```

I think this should help you understand.